# Ignoring Exception in_onmessage

Tags: python, discord

I am new to making Discord Bots using Discord API and python, and apparently my code is acting a bit strange since i added Databases, i have used replit for the coding.

My code is:

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json

client = discord.Client()

def get_quote():
    response = requests.get("http://zenquotes.io/api/random")
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    quote = json_data[0]['q'] + " -" + json_data[0]['a']
    return quote

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('{0.user}'.format(client) + ' has successfully logged in.')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('.ltt help'):
        await message.channel.send('hello')
    
    if input.content.startswith('.ltt inspire'):
      quote = get_quote()
      await message.channel.send(quote)
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

And when i try to execute it, it gives me the following error after sucessfully executing:
[image]

The error causes the bot to be unresponsive, even after mutliple triez of executing `.ltt inspire` and `.ltt help`, it seems their is a bug, or error. Even after rechecking the code the error persists.

Note: The following code is from a tutorial, if you want to refer to that here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPTfmiYiuok
Note: I had not merged `.ltt inspire` and `.ltt help` before. When I did `.ltt inspire` was the only code that worked. `.ltt help` is not responding.

Comment: You appear to have a typo in the third `if`, where you're checking `input.content` instead of `message.content` (which you're using in the previous `if`).

Comment: @Blckknght Thank you, only now do i realize that i had such a stupid error. Now the program works as intended. Please post the comment in the answers section so I can mark as correct

Answer (score 0):

```
if message.content.startswith('.ltt inspire'):
      quote = get_quote()
      await message.channel.send(quote)
```

just make sure whenever you start a new line in on_message() you always stat that it is a message and not an input